# C++ #include external function issue

Tags: c++, c, function, linker, include

I'm a real beginner and I'm programming in C++ using Visual Studio.
I've a simple cpp code that recalls some functions written in a .c and .h file. I included that file by means of #include directive and the IDE "sees" the function.
When I compile, I get this

Error 7 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _IMUsendAccelToFIFO referenced in function _main D:\Cprojects\Pencil\Pencil\Pencil.obj Pencil

What am I missing here?

Thank you all!

Comment: Are you linking it correctly? It seems a linker error, is the .o file generated from the .c file passed to the linker?

Comment: @Ass3mbler: If he's using VS that should be handled for him if it's his own code. I think it's probably more a problem that he isn't linking a required library in with his project.

Comment: In silico: It's C related (read his question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get an error in Visual Studio you can actually google for the error code and you will get pretty extensive information for that. In this case, googling LNK2019 gives this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z(VS.80).aspx) as first hit, which also provides some examples on how you get the error.
Your vendor should have provided some .lib files for you (usually found in a folder named lib?). Make sure that these are added in the project via:

- Project >  Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > *Additional Dependencies*

You could also see if there is any "get started" information for you from your vendor, which explains which dependencies you have to include in your project.
If you feel unsure of what a compiler and what a linker does, [pick up a book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/238902) that explains it, or browse some [free alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/238902).

Answer (score 3):

It is a linker error, not a compiler error.  The compiler is happy, it saw the declaration of function in the .h file.  The linker isn't, it cannot find the *definition* of the function.

Add the .c file to your project.

Comment: the .c files are alrady in the project as "external dependencies", when I try to add them as "source files" I get this:

Error 1 error C1853: 'Debug\Pencil.pch' precompiled header file is from a previous version of the compiler, or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa) d:\cprojects\pencil\pencil\imufifo.c 1 1 Pencil

Comment: @Stefano: Then simply delete that old `.pch` file (or disable precompiled headers entirely).

Comment: Right-click the .c file in the Solution Explorer window.  Properties, C/C++, Precompiled Headers, change "Create/Use" to Not Using.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [ghettopilot](http://code.google.com/p/ghettopilot/)? that's the only reference I can find on the web to the function you're missing. If you are, then you need to include the .lib file for that library in your link options.

Comment: No I'm just importing some libraries I got from the vendor af the system I'm using, so they just should work

Comment: @Stefano: see if there are any tutorials on how to set it up from your vendor.

Comment: The function that you're missing is from your vendor, who by the looks of it are using the library I mentioned. Make sure that you are linking in all your vendor libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio will compile .c files as C and .cpp files as C++ by default, and this can cause trouble because if you want to call functions defined in a .c file from a .cpp file, then you must wrap the header in `extern "C" { }`, as the compiler will expect all functions not declared `extern "C"` to be from C++. This is because of an implementation detail called name mangling. Alternatively, you could force all files to be compiled as C or as C++ in the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Thank you very much!
The libraries I was using needed to be built. I tried but I couldn't build them as I used to get "heap space" error!

I installed Visual Studio 2005 (with which the code was produced by the vendor) and it worked at first attempt! There are probably some back-compatibility issues..